# Should I have trust in the system time?

Tags: datetime, logging, time, utc

Whenever I log something i ask myself: "What if this runs on an computer with incorrect time settings?"

The local time can be wrong but am I right that this might also be the case with UTC time?

My current approach is to get the NIST time and just write it on top of every log file together with the UTC and local time so the user looking at the log file can see how the time inside the log is related to the real world time.

Is this correct behaviour to print NIST + UTC + Local time on top of every logfile + a small info message on how time work?

This of course assumes that if their clock is incorrect it stays incorrect in the same way throuout the full log file

Comment: I feel that this belongs more on [Programmers.SE]

Comment: @cat when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat well, my assumptions are 1) OP wouldn't bother cross-posting unless this one gets closed / answered and 2) this one will either be satisfactorily answered or closed, and either way it won't be cross-posted in a way that breaks the rules. I understand your point, though :)

Comment: I find your lack of faith [in the system time] disturbing.

Comment: @BlackAdder shouldn't we be pessimistic about everything the user has control of?